# Java Regex Match Pattern Groups unexpectedly matched

Tags: java, regex

I want to catch groups between curly brackets and below pattern is succeed

`String pattern = "(\\{.*?\\})+";`

example input

`String line = "I expect(dd) new five{I\r\nII} hundred dollars new test {$500} {$1}.";`

```
// Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern ,Pattern.DOTALL);

// Now create matcher object.
  Matcher matcher = r.matcher(line);
  while(matcher.find())
      {
          System.out.println( matcher.group());
      }
```

and the output as expected is

`{I\r\nII}`

`{$500}`

`{$1}`

but unexpectedly when I tried to catch groups with including `new` keyword

`String pattern = "(new.*\\{.*?\\})+";`

I got

`new five{I\r\nII} hundred dollars new test {$500} {$1}`

I was expected the output would be

`new five{I\r\nII}`

`new test {$500}`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Use non greedy `.*?` quantifier.

Comment: What @WiktorStribiżew means is, your pattern should be `(new.*?\\{.*?\\})`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks

Comment: @Abra thanks , yes it works